# Heroku: Redirect / to /features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

How can I have make auto redirecting every user who goes to mysite.com/ to mysite.com/features?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your root route to direct folks there (these are Rails 3 routes):

**in config/routes.rb**

```
root "content#features"
```

**in app/controllers/contents_controller.rb**

```
class ContentsController < ApplicationController
  def features
  end
end
```

That won't do a redirect, however.  To do that, you'll need something like this:
**in config/routes.rb**

```
match "features" => "contents#features", :as => "features"
root "content#index"
```

**in app/controllers/contents_controller.rb**

```
class ContentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to features_url
  end
  def features

  end
end
```